# keeping track of deleted posts without using wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress

i have 2 wordpress websites `A` and `B`.

if `A` somehow changes (adding a post , editing a post , deleting a post ) , B needs to change as well .

so in `A` by using a php robot which is checking database every couple of minutes  ,  i,ve created a json feed for `added` and `edited` posts of `A` .

it's easy to track added/edited posts by checking `wp_posts` table . but i can't find a way to know which posts have been deleted ( Delete Permanently ).

this script is suppose to be portable and usable for people who are not programmer , so i dont want to use wordpress functions or do any change/addition to wordpress system .

so is there any way to find deleted posts by checking the database or something like that  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for posts in the trash by using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'trash'
```

but if you are trying to find posts that have been removed from the database you will need to either track the missing IDs in the `wp_posts` table or add some functionality to track when a post is deleted. You can do this by using the `delete_post` action hook in your theme:

```
function my_tracking_function() {
    // Put ID into new database table
}
add_action( 'delete_post', 'my_tracking_function', 1 );
```

And then pass that table to the other site for processing. Once both sites are synced you can run a cleanup routine to empty the tracking table. **I realize that this is partially using Wordpress functionality, but the passing of the table data can be done outside of Wordpress using SQL.**

Comment: thanx ,  apparently it's impossible without using wordpress functions  , as i thought